# Specify the configuration to be used in Specs2 tests with Play 2.4

Tags: scala, specs2, playframework-2.4

I am trying to run some Specs2 tests in Play 2.4 with Scala. But because the application depends on some Guice DI modules, I would need to have the configurations available that these modules require, even if my tests do not directly depend on these modules.

I have a `conf/dev.conf` file that contains the necessary configurations. This file also includes the default `conf/application.conf`.

How can I make my Specs2 tests use the alternative `conf/dev.conf` when running the tests in Play 2.4?

I've looked around Stackoverflow and it seems some other advice are available, but they apply to Play 2.3 or older. Any help? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting something like this in your `build.sbt`:

```
fork in Test := true 
javaOptions in Test += "-Dconfig.resource=dev.conf"
```

This will enable forking for tests that allows you to specify custom parameters for the JVM for different environments.

See [specifying an alternative configuration file](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/Configuration#Specifying-an-alternative-configuration-file) and [SBT's various forking options](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.12.3/docs/Detailed-Topics/Forking.html#forked-jvm-options).

Comment: Thanks a lot! This helped me on the way, but I also had to enable forking for tests with 'fork in Test := true'. I also used config.resource=dev.conf instead. I edited the answer to reflect these changes. Waiting for the edit to be peer reviewed.

Comment: @JohanPaul Glad you got it to work. According to the [Play SBT cookbook](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/SBTCookbook#Fork-and-parallel-execution-in-test) `fork in Test := true` should be the default, so I'm not sure why it wouldn't work for you otherwise.

Comment: Interesting. Initially the line from your original answer above didn't work for me so I read a bit more, I then added the fork option and "at some point" the tests started working. Not sure then if it was that line in particular that solved the case or not.

Comment: You are right; I removed the fork line from the build.sbt and it still works. So must have been the other tweaks I did to the line that helped.